# OnTouchListener handles Touch even after finish();

Tags: android, android-activity, ontouchlistener

I have a simple android Activity with an OnTouchListener.
There I have a button, which starts another Activity and finishes the current one (with finish();). Now the problem is that while the next Activity is loading (and the screen is black) the Touch-events already get processed, so when the loading is done, some things are pressed already. I want the TouchListener to start working when the Activity is done loading and not halfway through.

I already tried delaying the View.setOnTouchListener(this); but it doesnt work. Touch events still get processed before the new Activity even started.

Here is an example:

```
public class Testclass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    GLSurfaceView glsv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glsv = new GLSurfaceView();
        glSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v2, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            startNextActivity();
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So if this Activity would start another instance of itself through 'startNextActivity();' and if I doubletapped the screen, the second Activity would close itself too (right after its done loading) and start a third Activity.

All I want is that the second Activity only responds to Touch events after it is done loading. How do I achieve this?

and obviously the example code is not completed but I think all the relevant parts are shown.

Comment: Did you consider to manage the return type of onTouch() in other functions of the activities' lifetime? You can do that in either the onStart()/onStop() or onResume()/onPause() functions? Since onResume()/onPause manage the foreground lifetime of the activity, I suppose this is what you want to look at?

Comment: as far as I know the method finish(); already starts onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your onTouch() always returns true to indicate that the touch event was handled. Now, theoretically I would guess that you might want to make this a variable and set the value default to false in onCreate(). Set the variable to true in onResume() and set it to false in onPause().

Comment: already tried this. It does not affect anything since there is always only one listener active at a time. Still the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found to this type of issue is achieved by leveraging [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html):

In onCreate of 2nd Activity:

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//Prevents from any clicks outside ProgressDialog being detected
progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); 
progress.setTitle("Please Wait"); //Or whatever you want it to say
progress.setMessage("Loading Second Activity...");
progress.show();
```

and then once the all of the data for this Second activity has been loaded call:

```
progress.dismiss();
```

This should not only give your users feedback on what is happening with the blank screen they are seeing, but also disables them from generating any OnTouchEvents to be processed until the screen is fully loaded.

Let me know if you have any trouble implementing this solution and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: so I implement the first code block right after starting the next activity and then use 'progress.dismiss();' at the end of the second activities oncreate method? the second activity doesnt have the same "progress" instance initialized... where else do i implement this?

Comment: Implement starting progress in the onCreate(...) of the second activity, not the first. What type of data are you loading that makes the page take awhile to load? Which method is loading this data? Are you building a ListAdapter, loading images, etc? However this loading is done progress.dismiss() should be called after this loading is complete. All Progress management will take place in the second activity

Comment: Does not work. The problem is not that the Touch instantly gets handled by the Activity, but it seems like all Touch-events get queued somewhere and then played once the Activity is done loading. I do not have enough background-knowledge about how the onTouchListener queues those events... I would just have to delete this queue once the activity is done loading.

Comment: Hmmm sorry to hear that. By "Does not work" do you mean you cannot get it to implement? or are you able to get the ProgressDialog to start and dismiss, but click events are still being queued? Still do not understand what you are loading in this activity that is taking it so long. Sorry I haven't been able to help but keep getting back to me with details and I'll try my best to help figure out what is going on

Comment: My Activity is a little graphical game. It takes like 1 second to load all images and stuff. I implemented your suggestion but the touch events still get queued and played afterwards. The loadingtime is not the problem. If I am in another Activity and doubleclick a button which should start the next Activity, then the second click of the doubleclick will trigger my "Touch screen to start game" event.

Comment: I just realised that your answer works! I just implemented your code right at the beginning of onCreate(), thats why it didnt work. Now I found out that it has to be AFTER the line "view.setOnTouchListener(this);" then it works fine. I edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean flag at the end of the OnCreate method of your activity, and use it to force the touch event to wait until it becomes true.

For example:

```
boolean flag = false;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    glsv = new GLSurfaceView();
    glSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    flag = true;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v2, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        flag = false;    //Just use it if you cal this activity again on startNextActivity()
        startNextActivity();
        while(!flag){}    //Wait for flag to become true
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
```

This way, flag will become true when activity it's created.

Comment: for some reason the while loop doesnt end. something must be wrong with my code...

Comment: Ok, replace the next:

    while(!flag){}
    finish();

With:

    if(flag)  {

        finish();
    }

This will execute the finish if activity has finished first.

Comment: already tried this before your suggestion. seems like the second ontouchlistener is the one who gets the actions, not the first. i dont know nothing seems to work :(

Comment: a few. it doesnt matter which one i start, it always preactivates the ontouchlistener

Comment: I guess you can do this:

    startNextActivity();

And on NextActivity, at the bottom of onCreate, do this:

    FirstActivity.finish();

Comment: And how do I receive the first Activities Context?

Comment: You Should Use An Intent, Like This:

First you import the Intent Class.

    import android.content.Intent;

Then at the moment you will launch your new activity, you create an intent object.

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrentActivity.class);
    
And finally, start new activity from intent.

    startActivity(intent);

You also can add some extras to intent before launching the new activity, (Text, Object, Etc), and catch them on the new activity to use.

For example, you can add the text from an EditText Object to the intent, and then when you launch the new one, you can use it.